# How to use the proxy automatically when a 403 status code is encountered by the scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

In the process of grabbing, 403 status codes are encountered.
The requirement is: automatically use the agent when 403 status code is encountered.

The check and response to the status code is configured in downloadermiddleware, but seems to work only for the first link

```
def process_response(self, request, response, spider):

    status_code = [403]
    if response.status in status_code:
        spider.logger.debug('Error ======= %s %s , 开始使用 Proxy 代理' % (response.status, request.url))
        import importlib
        settings = importlib.import_module('settings')
        proxy = AbuYunProxyMiddleware(settings=settings)
        request.meta['proxy'] = proxy.proxy_server
        request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = proxy.proxy_authorization
        return request
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you create a new class inheriting `scrapy`'s `RetryMiddleware`, and override the `process_response` function.

```py
def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    if request.meta.get('dont_retry', False):
        return response
    if response.status in self.retry_http_codes:
        reason = response_status_message(response.status)
        # Add your proxy
        request.meta["proxy"] = PROXY
        return self._retry(request, reason, spider) or response
    return response
```

Comment: Did what you said, but not yet. Comments can't be coded.

Comment: 我把修改的文件上传到了：https://github.com/kjxy/wjselenium 运行的结果跟预想有很大差距。帮忙看下，谢谢~

Comment: @L.S scrapy默认会加载原本的RetryMiddleware，应该是同时加载了一个它的一个你的中间件导致的。改一下中间件Base配置试试，吧他的替换成你自己的， 别加载成两次就好：https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#downloader-middlewares-base

Comment: 太好了，把默认的重试中间件关掉就可以了。但是也可能因此产生别的影响。我提问中的代码，讲道理也没啥问题...也能进入添加代理的步骤，就是只有起始页能从403到200，详情页还是一直403

Comment: 我测试过头部信息，这个网站不验证。如果起始页就是详情页，我的代码也能访问详情页。但是当起始页是列表页的时候，就只能访问列表页，详情页全是403

Comment: 我又用我的代码测了一下，https://github.com/kjxy/wjselenium 很奇怪，前3次重试都没有使用代理（403状态码），第四次使用了，并且可以正常访问

Comment: 检查下代码，log还是默认的retrymiddleware打印出来的，不太确定你的middleware有没有执行。